# Error in making DLL class in Eclipse IDE with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++

I make a project in Eclipse to export a dll class with g++ compiler. My OS is Ubuntu and the application will run in Ubuntu OS. I created a shared project.

I have compile error as

```
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token   OCR_dll.h   /OCR    line 19 C/C++ Problem
```

The error happened at  `#define DLLCLASS __declspec(dllexport)` and how to solve the error. Thank you.

My dll codes header file is

```
OCR_dll.h
#ifndef OCR_DLL_H_
#define OCR_DLL_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Define.h"

#ifdef EXPORT
#define DLLCLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLCLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

using namespace cv;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM {
    class iOCR{

        public:
            virtual ~iOCR(){}
            virtual int preProcessing(Mat &img) = 0;
            virtual int textExtraction(Mat &img) = 0;
    };

    class OCR : public iOCR{

        public:
            OCR(){}
            ~OCR(){ ; }
            int preProcessing(Mat &img);
            int textExtraction(Mat &img);
        private:


    };

    extern "C"{ DLLCLASS iOCR* __stdcall  createOCRObject(); };
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* OCR_DLL_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. In Linux environment, dll is called shared library.
The way I create the shared lib is

```
Headerfile  
    #ifndef OCR_DLL_H_   
    #define OCR_DLL_H_

    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Define.h"


    using namespace cv;



    namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM {
        class iOCR{

            public:
                virtual ~iOCR(){}
                virtual int preProcessing(Mat &img) = 0;
                virtual int textExtraction(Mat &img) = 0;
        };

        class OCR : public iOCR{

            public:
                OCR(){}
                ~OCR(){ ; }
                int preProcessing(Mat &img);
                int textExtraction(Mat &img);
            private:


        };



    }


    #endif /* OCR_DLL_H_ */

CPP file
#include "OCR_dll.h"



namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM {
    extern "C" iOCR* create_object(){
        iOCR *p = new OCR();
        return p;
    }

    extern "C" void destroy_object( iOCR* object )
    {
      delete object;
    }

    int OCR::preProcessing(Mat &img){


        return SUCCESS;
    }

    int OCR::textExtraction(Mat &img){


        return SUCCESS;
    }
}

MAKEFILE
g++ -fPIC -shared OCR_dll.cpp -o OCR_dll.so
```

Then we can create shared lib object for a class.